# Project Compilation Error - ld.exe cannot find glut32.lib

Tags: c++, eclipse, glut, configure

I'm desperately trying to configure glut with the Eclipse CDT plugin and have been failing to do so for the past couple hours.  I downloaded the most recent version of glut [here](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html). And have placed the various files and such in the places tutorials have indicated with little luck.

When I build this is what I get:

```
    g++ "-LC:\\MinGW\\lib\\glut" -o MidpointAlgorithm.exe "MidpointAlgorithm\\Main.o"      
    "MidpointAlgorithm\\LineAlgorithm.o" "MidpointAlgorithm\\EllipseAlgorithm.o"   
    "MidpointAlgorithm\\CircleAlgorithm.o" "-lC:\\MinGW\\lib\\glut\\glut32.lib" "-
    lC:\\MinGW\\lib\\glut\\glut32.dll" 
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -  
    lC:\MinGW\lib\glut\glut32.lib
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find - 
    lC:\MinGW\lib\glut\glut32.dll
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have attempted quite a few fixes that I have come across in my search for the answer.  I have updated libraries with the location of the files and the library path.  In the above error the places that the files cannot be found are where the files are located.  I have tried to only add the name of the file (so "glut32" instead of "C:\....\glut32.lib") and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Do you have a `glut32.lib` or `glut32.dll` on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have both in the places that the system says they can't be found.

Comment: What if you remove the `-l` before `C:\\...\\glut32.lib`, and remove the `.dll` one?

Comment: I'm not putting that in there.  The build does it for me for some reason. The -l is for the library I think.  I thought that was the problem too but there's no way, that I can see, to remove it.

Comment: Oh, so that `g++` line is not something that you are creating? How are you telling eclipse to add those libraries?

Comment: Right click the project >> Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> MinGW C++ Linker >> Libraries >> add file